# game center unavailable player is not signed in

Tags: iphone, ios6, game-center

On iOS 6 when a player is not signed in and is trying to use GameCenter an UIAlertView with the text that i put in title pops up. "game center unavailable player is not signed in". My question is is it possible to replace that UIAlertView with anything else, with my own interface element?

```
[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error)
            {
                    if ([[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] isAuthenticated])
                    {
                        NSLog(@"[gamecenter] player authenticated: %@\n", [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer]);
                        [self gamecenterLoadAchievements];

                        [GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker].inviteHandler = ^(GKInvite *acceptedInvite, NSArray *playersToInvite)
                        {
                            // Insert application-specific code here to clean up any games in progress.
                            if (acceptedInvite)
                            {
                                NSLog(@"Accepted invitation");

                                isInvited = YES;

                                [[GameLevel sharedGameLevel] setCurrentGameMode:GameModeGameCenter];

                                GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithInvite:acceptedInvite] autorelease];
                                mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;

                                AppDelegate * delegate = (AppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
                                [delegate.viewController presentModalViewController:mmvc animated:YES];

                            }
                            else if (playersToInvite)
                            {
                                NSLog(@"Players to invite");

                                GKMatchRequest *request = [[[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
                                request.minPlayers = 2;
                                request.maxPlayers = 2;
                                request.playersToInvite = playersToInvite;

                                GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request] autorelease];
                                mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;
                                [presentingViewController presentModalViewController:mmvc animated:YES];
                            }

                        };
                    }
                    else
                    if (viewController)
                    {
                        AppDelegate          *delegate        = (AppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
                        NavigationController *_viewController = delegate.viewController.navController;

                        [_viewController presentViewController: viewController animated: YES completion:nil];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NSLog(@"[gamecenter] %@\n", error);

                        gcLoginFailed = YES;
                        if ([[error domain] isEqualToString:GKErrorDomain])
                        {
                            if ([error code] == GKErrorNotSupported)
                                gcIsSupported = NO;
                            else
                                if ([error code] == GKErrorCancelled)
                                    gcLoginCancelled = YES;
                        }
                    }
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Just not use UIAlertView Use your own graphics with a UIButton

If you are using the disableGameCenter method in authenticating , just don't use it , instead of it use a integer ilk int isPlayerSignedIn . And just return it to 1 or 0 . So ;

```
if (isPlayerSignedIn==0) {

   //display your graphics

} 
else do nothing .
```

edit :

```
else
if (viewController)
{
    AppDelegate          *delegate        = (AppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NavigationController *_viewController = delegate.viewController.navController;
    [_viewController presentViewController: viewController animated: YES completion:nil];
}
```

just if you don't use these lines of code you will see that you don't get that UIAlertView

Then you can implement a "game center is unavailable" staff , but additionally you have to implement a login screen too.

Comment: really? and how do i get access to that UIAlertView to be able to replace it with my own graphics?

Comment: If you post your authentication code then I can say something , and your showleaderboard code

Comment: are you creating that UIAlertView or the system doing that ?

Comment: GameKit is doing that, wouldn't i be able to understand how to deal with an UIAlertView launched by me?

Comment: Just if you post a code especially authenticating code , I'll write what to change or if it's can't change

Comment: The important part is how you are disabling the game center for user